# How can I provide credentials to PHPUnit tests

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, command-line-interface

I have an API classes library, but testing it requires API key. Of course the key is not public and there is my question. How can I provide credentials to PHPUnit configuration, so everyone could run the tests? Does PHPUnit allow to pass options via command line?

Answer (score 2):

You could set an environment variable before running the tests, then retrieve it in your tests using `getenv`. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
API_KEY=secretapikey
phpunit <parameters>
```

Then in your PHP files:

```
$apiKey = getenv('API_KEY');
```

Comment: @still, in Windows, you can use a `.bat` file and use the syntax `SET API_KEY=secretapikey` to set the env variable. The rest should be the same.

Comment: You could use the bootstrap.php file to set the API key as well.

Answer (score 1):

Might have a look at the '-d' option to PhpUnit it's meant to set php.ini option but you can read that with a simple $setting = ini_get('my_setting'); in setup(). Here's the link for the page in the [manual for PhpUnit](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html) and [for PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php).